# Please propose a idea to make a printable report to work

Tags: asp.net, printing

I am to produace printable report of a web page having control datalist which dispay data 
in two coumns.
Each cell of datalist columns has got some data, that i need to produce on a 8.5X11 size 
page with the following dimaesions which client has given me.

```
Dimensions for Custom Label Fields: 
Top Margin: 0”
Side Margin: 0” 
Vertical Pitch: 3”
Horizontal Pitch: 4”
Page Size: 8.5 x 11

Label Height: 3”
Label Width: 4” 
Number Across: 2
Number Down: 3

PAGE Top Margin: 2” 
PAGE Side Margin: .5” 
This creates the backwards L shape that allows our margins for perforation.
```

And client wants me to produce 6 cells on each specified size page 
each label on the page will acquire 1 cell, perferation are there on the page which separates 
the all 6 labels on the page.

Any how i managed to produce the specied dimensions on the perticular size paper for printing.
But some times, it goes abberant, like browser don't support page break dont work or some CSS 
issues or alignemnt get fail.
Which all annoyed to the client because he was saying if near future we slightly change the lable size or manyfactuing company
chang paper size then what, and he told if this keep heppening then we may stuck some 
time. So he was telling me for a windows application, but i never made a report in windows 
aplication before. Now, i am thinking that, fro windows appliaction i have to set dimensions
too. Then what is the purpose to have a windows application.
Please suggest me what should i do to make this report work, if i should start making a 
windows appiation to form that report then what should be my approach and what controls 
should i use, and how should i make it dynamic so that if in near future clients page size or label size slightely 
get changed then he can print all successfully.
IF any alternet best idea there exist then pelase propose.

Comment: To make it a windows application how should i approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you obtain the information from the web page (either using an API or a good scraper) and then format it into a PDF using a good reporting toolkit for printing purposes.

Using CSS and relying on a browser for pixel perfect positioning is a bad idea in general.

Comment: Yes, you are true, i can't depend on CSS. I research on what you said.

Comment: If the answer is what you're looking for, it's customary to upvote/accept it.

Comment: can you suggest me some api/ scraper name.

Comment: i haevn't find the best solution yet, i am seeking more answers. I know that.

Comment: I don't use `asp.net` but if I were doing this in Python, I'd default to [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for scraping and [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/) to generate the PDF. I don't know what equivalents exist in the `asp.net` ecosystem.

Comment: But don't you think if first i produce all web page content to PDF form, again i'll be in the same misery, how to set the proper dimension, if i give print out then will come comfortable to all labels.

Comment: CSS is better at presenting documents for the web. You don't need pixel perfect positioning over there and you thing can scale according to resolution etc. PDFs are designed for the print world and you need to position things based on paper size and things like that. It's well suited to do stuff like that and will fit on the given paper if printed. e.g. I use [this](http://nibrahim.net.in/2010/12/30/calligraphic_rulings.html) script to create ruling sheets I use to practice writing on where I need to have millimeter level control. It does the job very well.